# Quick Jquery Question: Scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-scrollable

I am working on a site, the demo is located here: http://waterwing.waterwing.ca (Please ignore the other 2 pages, they are far from finished).

Anyways, The scrollable on the home page works fine except for the fact that anything you click within the scrollpane will move the scroller. I need to make it so that only the arrows will move the scroller. I also believe this is only happening in mac safari and mac firefox because windows firefox seems to be fine.

The piece of jquery controlling the scroller:

```
$("#flowpanes").scrollable({size: 1});
```

I just need to alter this so that only the arrows can control movement and not anything inside the flowpanes div.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to add some other properties to the scrollable object. The whole list of properties can be found [here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable.html).

I think the one you're looking for is 'clickable' and it should be set to false. You can also add custom next and previous classes if you so choose. Should look like:

```
$("#flowpanes").scrollable({
    size: 1,
    clickable: false,
    nextPage: '.yourRightArrowClass',
    prevPage: '.yourLeftArrowClass'
});
```

You can play with the options though and see what works for you.